# Accelerating Conjugate Gradients fitting for small localized kernel (like cubic B-spline)

Tags: preconditioning, conjugate-gradient, b-spline, convolution

**Question:**

Is there some [pre-conditioner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner#Preconditioned_iterative_methods) for Conjugate-Gradient (CG) cheap enough, that it is worth using even if my operator is very local (i.e. already has a low number of non-zero elements), as it is when fitting B-spline functions?

or any other way how to improve the speed of CG convergence?

**Background:**

I fit function described on 2D/3D grid using localized basis function (e.g. B-splines) using Conjugate Gradient (CG) algorithm.

The least-square fitting reduce to soltion of this matrix problem:

$(B^T B) {\vec x}= B {\vec b}$

where $B$ is overlap-matrix between the basis function. Iterative method like CG use matrix-vector multiplications:

$\vec{y} = (B^T B) \vec{x}$

which in my case reduces into 2D/3D convolution with a stencil formed by tensor-product of 1D Cubic Spline (i.e. 3x3 or 3x3x3 tensor in 2D/3D case)

e.g. for 2D case:

$$[
[1,4,1],
[4,16,4],
[1,4,1], 
]$$

You can see that this matrix is very sparse and relatively cheap (although not so cheap if the grid has ~1 million points).

Is there any preconditioner other than [Diagonal Jacobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner#Jacobi_(or_diagonal)_preconditioner) worth using in such a situation?

Currently CG takes 50 iterations ot achieve $10^{-6}$ preccision:

```
CG[1] err 0.126261 
CG[2] err 0.052267 
CG[3] err 0.0294687 
CG[4] err 0.0193294 
...
CG[47] err 4.449e-05 
CG[48] err 4.24922e-05 
CG[49] err 3.60459e-05 
CG[50] err 3.32389e-05
```

Just in case code can be found here ([1](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/ProbeParticleModel/blob/OpenCL/cpp/fitSpline.cpp),[2](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/ProbeParticleModel/blob/OpenCL/cpp/CG.h),[3](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/ProbeParticleModel/blob/OpenCL/pyProbeParticle/fitSpline.py)) (but not sure if it is easy to understand)

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can try using Gauss-Seidel based preconditioning that is relatively easy to construct and is cheap enough (by my assessment) to give it a try.

Other choices of algebraic preconditioners (say, [incomplete LU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_LU_factorization)) might be too heavy relative to their potential impact.

I would also suggest looking into a full sparse direct solution of your problem. There are quite efficient implementations of sparse direct solvers nowadays, so it might be a reasonable alternative. By quick googling I was able to find at least [this publicstion](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0173857); however, I bet there are more canonical papers of this flavor.